# Enable Chrome Extension in Puppeteer version 10.1.0

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer

I am attempting to open Chrome with Puppeteer enabling a Chrome extension.
I have been searching for solutions and have tried to implement many with no success.

`chrome://version/`

*Google Chrome: 91.0.4472.164 (Official Build) (x86_64)*

*Revision:  541163496c9982c98f61819bab7cf2183ea8180f-refs/branch-heads/4472@{#1569}*

*OS:    macOS Version 10.15.7*

*JavaScript:    V8 9.1.269.39*

*Executable Path:   /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome*

*Puppeteer: 10.1.0*

**Code (one of many attempts, but latest):**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const path = require('path');

const extension_id_string = 'copjnifc....example.....gaodgpbh';
const extension_version = '1.5.1_0';
const extension_path = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../..', `/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/${extension_id_string}/${extension_version}`);

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
            `--load-extension=${extension_path}`,
            `--disable-extensions-except=${extension_path}`
        ]
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('http://google.com');
})();
```

I've used Node JS `path` module to get absolute path to the extensions directory.

On running the code with `Node v14.17.1` Chromium opens a browser and an alert pops up saying:

alert => *Failed to load extension from: . Manifest file is missing or unreadable*

When I follow the `extension_path` (denoted above on line 6) in terminal I can see a Manifest.json file, so there is one.

What am I missing here? Am I defining the path to the extension incorrectly? Or do I need to set the `executablePath` for my current Chrome path inside the options when launching a browser? (I did try this with no success).

```
const chrome_executablePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../..', '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome')

...

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: chrome_executablePath, //<-- added this line in previous attempts, but still didn't work
        args: [
            `--load-extension=${extension_path}`,
            `--disable-extensions-except=${extension_path}`
        ]
    })

...
```

Any pointers / help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do three things here:

1. Check if the manifest.json is encoded to UTF-8.
2. Make sure your extension path points to the extension area (i.e development area).
3. After headless false, add "devtools: true" option.